# Bug CheckBox and useState Reactjs with Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, material-ui, javascript-objects

I have a numeric select, when I select a number the component is rendered N times, the component has several checkboxes inside if I activate one the others are activated and that should not happen

[image]

Annex code in sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-hill-li6529?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I believe that issue here is that when React tries to update the state, it can't be sure of which element in the array to update, so it updates all of them to be safe.

One possible solution, with minimum code changes is to transform the state from an array to an object (having the index as key), so that when you set the  state you can specify which key should be updated.

The code changes that are needed here are the following:

- On the state initialisation (App.js):

```
const [wizard, setWizard] = useState({});
```

- On wizard initialisation (App.js):

```
for (let count = 0; count < sizeSelect; count++) {
   list[count] = { ...obj, id: count + 1, nameTable: `Users ${count}` }
}
```

- On rendering the wizard (App.js):

```
{Object.values(wizard).map((service, index) => (
    <Wizard .... />
))}
```

- On handleChange() function (Wizard.js):

```
const handleChange = (code, value) => {
  const auxWizard = {
    ...wizard,
    [index]: {
      ...wizard[index],
      apiServices: {
        ...wizard[index].apiServices,
        [code]: {
          ...wizard[index].apiServices[code],
          active: !value
        }
      }
    }
  };

  setChange(auxWizard);
};
```